# postgresqlでテーブルをcreate, insert, refreshした時間を取得したい

Tags: postgresql

テーブルについての最終更新が行われた日時を知りたいのですが、
どのようなクエリを書いたらよろしいでしょうか。
テーブルについてinsertしたり、
マテリアライズドビューをcreate, refreshした最終時刻を取得したいです。

いろいろ調べてみたのですが、

```
select *
from pg_stat_all_tables
```

の`last_autoanalyze`が一番近い時間が出ているような気がするのですが、そうでないものもありよくわかりません。（この変数の意味は何なのでしょう？）

**追記**
last_analyze : テーブルが手作業で解析された最終時刻です。
last_autoanalyze : 自動バキュームデーモンによりテーブルが解析された最終時刻です。
とあるので更新とはあまり関係ないようですね。

**更に追記**
`SELECT * FROM pg_stat_file('filename');`
は
`permission denied for function pg_stat_file`
でした。

superuserでないと実行できないようです。

**実行環境**
postgresql 12.3

Comment: PostgreSQLテーブルの作成日時と更新日時の取得について(　https://qiita.com/yaju/items/014f0279fb2114d6c22a　)を見つけました。参考になるかもしれません。